# python downloaded module .py file: How to import?

Tags: python, python-import

If I have only downloaded a  some_module.py file, how can I use it in a way just by typing

```
import some_module ?
```

Do I need to put this .py file in some specific folder or I need to type some commands in the command line?

Thanks

Comment: put it in the same folder that you have the file that's going to use it

Comment: Could alternatively do `from some_module import function`

Comment: Python [has documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to add the py at the end. The file should be in the same folder as the other file.